# JQuery hover activated repeatably by subelements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code

```
<div id="{{_id}}" class="actor">
    <span>{{name}}</span>
    <span class="muted">- level {{level}}</span><br>

    <span><small>{{curHealth}}/{{maxHealth}} HP</small></span>
    <span><small>{{curAp}}/{{maxAp}} AP</small></span>
</div>
```

And I want to fire an event when I mouse over the outermost element of class 'actor'. This works, but the problem is that this event gets fired repeatably if I mouse over any of the subelements, such as the span tags. How can I avoid this?

EDIT:

```
'mouseover .actor': () ->
    $parent = $("##{this._id}").parent()
    if $parent.attr('id') is 'playerField'
        # do stuff related to friendly unit
    else if $parent.attr('id') is 'opponentField'
        console.log this
        Session.set('target', this)
```

I am using MeteorJS, and this method just translates into the standard .on event afaik

Thank

Comment: How are you implementing the hover?

Comment: updated post with code

Comment: If this uses jQuery, replace `mouseover`/`mouseout` with `mouseenter`/`mouseleave`

Comment: @Oriol - No it isn't. Still valid. http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-small-element

Comment: @j08691 Oh, true. I didn't HTML5 redefined it, I thought it was removed like `<big>`.

Comment: the mouseenter / mouseleave did the trick

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` are not exclusive of jQuery. Some old browsers don't support it natively, though.

Comment: @Oriol I didn't know they actually implemented them in recent (non-IE) browsers, thanks for the info. But the only recent compatibility table I could find about it [is on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseenter#Browser_compatibility). I didn't even know these events [made it into the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-mouseenter)... Good to know.